# InputStream.read() stuck

Tags: java, file, copy, inputstream, infinite-loop

I have searched for this problem but all people encoutering it are using sockets.
I am just using a solid file so everything should already be in the Stream ...
Here is my code :

```
            AudioInputStream in = null;
            MpegAudioFileReader mp = new MpegAudioFileReader();
            in = mp.getAudioInputStream(new File(this.directory + currentBeatmaps.get(0).getAudioFileName()));
            AudioFormat baseFormat = in.getFormat();
            AudioFormat decodedFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                    baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                    16,
                    baseFormat.getChannels(),
                    baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
                    baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
                    false);
            final AudioInputStream din2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(decodedFormat, in);

            long length = din2.getFrameLength();
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(din2);
            in.close();
            InputStream is1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

            AudioInputStream din = new AudioInputStream(
                    is1,
                    decodedFormat,
                    length
            );
```

IOUtils.toByteArray(din2) gets stuck for some files, and works for other files so I checked what was inside, and there is this function that gets stuck in debugging mode :

```
/**
 * Copies bytes from a large (over 2GB) <code>InputStream</code> to an
 * <code>OutputStream</code>.
 * <p>
 * This method uses the provided buffer, so there is no need to use a
 * <code>BufferedInputStream</code>.
 * <p>
 *
 * @param input the <code>InputStream</code> to read from
 * @param output the <code>OutputStream</code> to write to
 * @param buffer the buffer to use for the copy
 * @return the number of bytes copied
 * @throws NullPointerException if the input or output is null
 * @throws IOException          if an I/O error occurs
 * @since 2.2
 */
public static long copyLarge(final InputStream input, final OutputStream output, final byte[] buffer)
        throws IOException {
    long count = 0;
    int n;
    while (EOF != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        count += n;
    }
    return count;
}
```

It dies when doing input.read(buffer) at the first iteration.
And I repeat, this works for some files but not for others, so I don't know how to handle this...
If someone may at least find a solution to at least, detect when it will do this so I can print an error that would be great (This part is not critical to my software)

Comment: 'Everything should already be in the stream' is meaningless. The file is out there on the disk, not  'in the stream'. Is it a remote file?

Comment: No it's a file that I put into an AudioInputStream, and it is read entirely because it is not remotely transfered

Comment: It is 'read entirely' *when you have read it to end of stream,* not before, and 'because it is not remotely transferred' has nothing to do with it whatsoever.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, but if so, why does it get stuck when I do .read() ? I entered debug mode, and nothing happens as soon as I start to check the condition for EOF, at the first iteration

Comment: Why are you creating two `AudioInputStreams`? What was wrong with the first one?

Comment: I will be using it multiple times, so I clone the original one into a byteArray and then create a new AudioInputStream.

Comment: How large is you file?

Comment: The file will be from 1Mo to 20Mo, but more often around 2-6Mo

Comment: I was irritated by the “Copies bytes from a large (over 2GB) …” comment, but apparently `IOUtils` also uses this method when the size is unknown. A clear sign of overusing utility methods, using buffered I/O to write into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`… Still, it’s not clear why this causes problems. Is it hanging in either, `read` or `write` call or does that loop appear to be running forever?

Comment: It is hanging on the .read() method, when using the debugger it doesn't even enter the loop, it is stuck on the condition. I used "Step Into" when i was on the "while" line and it just sat there, and the first thing it was processing was .read()